# Jquery Validation Plugin (.validate) is not working in Dynamic Form(loop form)

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, jquery-validate

I am using the Jquery validation plugin to validate the  Dynamic Form.I am getting  error messages as wanted  but the main problem  is whether  the  required fields  are empty or not whatever  the condition   submit button stills  works. I am unable to stop the submit if required fields are empty. Here is the small piece of my code.

**HTML:**

```
<form class="pa-form" action="confirmed" method="post" id="my-form">
    <fieldset>
        <?php for($i=1;$i<=3;$i++){ ?>
        <div class="flabel-control">
          <input data-toggle="floatLabel" data-value="" name="myForm[first_name][]" class="firstname form-control" type="text" id="first-name<?=$i?>" required      placeholder="First name" spellcheck="false">
         </div>
        <div class="flabel-control">
          <input data-toggle="floatLabel" data-value="" name="myForm[last_name][]" class="firstname form-control" type="text" id="last-name<?=$i?>" required        placeholder="Last name" spellcheck="false">
         </div>
        <br>
        <?php };?>
           <div class="btn-holder">
            <input type="submit" id="submitBtn" class="btn btn-default text-uppercase" value="Confirm">
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

**Js:**

```
$("#my-form").validate({
          validClass: "valid",
          errorClass: "error",
          rules: {
            'myForm[first_name][]': "required",
            'myForm[last_name][]': "required",
          },
          messages: {
            'myForm[first_name][]': "First name is required",
            'myForm[last_name][]': "Last name is required",
            }
          }
    });
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24670447/how-to-validate-array-of-inputs-using-validate-plugin-jquery'

Comment: Solution their only works for single array .I cannot find solution for multi-dimensinal array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`jquery-validate` requires that each element have a unique name. So put the `for` loop index into the names.

```
    <?php for($i=1;$i<=3;$i++){ ?>
    <div class="flabel-control">
      <input data-toggle="floatLabel" data-value="" name="myForm[first_name][<?=$i?>]" class="firstname form-control" type="text" id="first-name<?=$i?>" required placeholder="First name" spellcheck="false">
     </div>
    <div class="flabel-control">
      <input data-toggle="floatLabel" data-value="" name="myForm[last_name][<?=$i?>]" class="firstname form-control" type="text" id="last-name<?=$i?>" required placeholder="Last name" spellcheck="false">
     </div>
    <br>
    <?php };?>
```

You don't need to list the elements specifically in the `rules`, because the plugin automatically processes the `required` attributes in the elements. But if you want to, you can do:

```
var rules = {}, messages = {};
for (var i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
    rules['myForm[firstname][' + i + ']'] = 'required';
    messages['myForm[firstname][' + i + ']'] = 'First name is required';
    rules['myForm[lastname][' + i + ']'] = 'required';
    messages['myForm[lastname][' + i + ']'] = 'Last name is required';
}
$("#my-form").validate({
      validClass: "valid",
      errorClass: "error",
      rules: rules,
      messages: messages
    }
});
```