# jQuery Validation How to concatenate array [] and :hidden simultaneously into ignore properties?

Tags: jquery, arrays, validation, input

I am running into a problem with jQuery Validation and need to ignore some fields.

I need to ignore hidden fields and array of input boxes using validation plugin.

Below is html code.

```
<form id="transport-form">
  <input type="text" name="qty[]" id="qty1">
  <input type="text" name="qty[]" id="qty2" style="display:none" >
  <input type="text" name="qty[]" id="qty3">
  <input type="text" name="qty[]" id="qty4">
  <input type="submit value="submit">
</form>
```

and jquery code is below

```
jQuery("#transport-form").validate({
        rules: {
            'qty[]': {
                required: true,
                ignore: '[],:hidden'
            }
        },
    });
```

I need to ignore [] because everytime i click submit it is validating only the first value. rest all the values of same name are not validated.

But i want ignore also hidden input (qty2)
Please help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to validate array of inputs using validate plugin jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24670447/how-to-validate-array-of-inputs-using-validate-plugin-jquery)

Comment: That incomplete solution does not solve my problem.

Comment: my problem is: How to concatenate array [] and :hidden  simultaneously into ignore properties?