# jQuery Validate to check that time value of a field doesn't fall between start and end time of an event having same date

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have a form where I have three input fields (one as date, one as start time and the other as end time) which are in arrays. Like this:-

```
<input type="text" class="form-control datetimepicker-input" data-target="#sDatePicker_1" data-toggle="datetimepicker" id="sdating_1" name="sdate[]" placeholder="Select Day"/>
<input type="text" class="form-control datetimepicker-input" data-target="#fromTimePicker_1" data-toggle="datetimepicker" id="stime_1" id="stime[]" placeholder="HH : MM"/>
<input type="text" class="form-control datetimepicker-input" data-target="#toTimePicker_1" data-toggle="datetimepicker" id="etime_1" id="etime[]" placeholder="HH : MM"/>
<input type="text" class="form-control datetimepicker-input" data-target="#sDatePicker_2" data-toggle="datetimepicker" id="sdating_2" name="sdate[]" placeholder="Select Day"/>
<input type="text" class="form-control datetimepicker-input" data-target="#fromTimePicker_2" data-toggle="datetimepicker" id="stime_2" id="stime[]" placeholder="HH : MM"/>
<input type="text" class="form-control datetimepicker-input" data-target="#toTimePicker_2" data-toggle="datetimepicker" id="etime_2" id="etime[]" placeholder="HH : MM"/>
<input type="text" class="form-control datetimepicker-input" data-target="#sDatePicker_3" data-toggle="datetimepicker" id="sdating_3" name="sdate[]" placeholder="Select Day"/>
<input type="text" class="form-control datetimepicker-input" data-target="#fromTimePicker_3" data-toggle="datetimepicker" id="stime_3" id="stime[]" placeholder="HH : MM"/>
<input type="text" class="form-control datetimepicker-input" data-target="#toTimePicker_3" data-toggle="datetimepicker" id="etime_3" id="etime[]" placeholder="HH : MM"/>
```

I am using [jQuery validate](https://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/) to validate the form. I need a jQuery form validation rule with specific requirement:

1. The date value can be same in multiple `sdate[]` field. This is
   because user can give multiple training session in one day.
2. If `sdate[]` value  is same for mulitple rows, then the value of
   `stime[]` and `etime[]` of one row must not clash/conflict or fall
   within the time period of any other `stime[]` and `etime[]` field
   have same `sdate[]` value.

For example, if `s_date_1` and `s_date_2` is both **07/10/2019** and if `stime_1` and `etime_1` is `08.00 AM` and `9.00 AM`, then `stime_2` can't be `08.30 AM`.

I know jQuery validation, but in this case I am clueless about how to start.

Comment: You have enough reputation to know that you are supposed to supply enough code for a MCVE, but you're just showing us a list of input elements.   Where is the rest of the relevant HTML markup of the form?  Where is the call to the `.validate()` method?  Where is your attempt at any of this?  If you're *"clueless about how to start"*, then start by clicking the [tag:jquery-validate] tag and doing a search.

Comment: Finally, one helpful tip, you cannot have multiple text elements sharing the same name, such as `sdate[]`.  For this plugin (this is also in the documentation) the input elements **must** have ***unique*** names.  There is no workaround for this and plenty of people have asked before.

Comment: @Sparky, I am very well accustomed with Jquery Validate plugin and have atleast worked 100+ different cases. This scenario is unique and I have no idea about how to write the rule for this **particular trivial** case. Why should I put a generic validation rule for the `sake of posting` if it won't be even distant closer for my requirement?

Comment: @Sparky. Jquery Validation works fine on array elements too, like `sdate[]` having same name. Please check this link:- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24670447/how-to-validate-array-of-inputs-using-validate-plugin-jquery

Comment: You are mistaken.  The answer on that question requires that you edit the programming of the plugin itself.   You should also read the documentation:  https://jqueryvalidation.org/reference/#link-markup-recommendations